# How to make textfile to save in program directory in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

As i have abandoned the array approach to the problem, i need to know how to make listbox to save in textfile always in program's directory so it can be used/accessed to populate a different listbox, any ideas? Below is my code.

```
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (.txt)|.txt" 
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() 
If SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then 
    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, False) 
        For Each itm As String In Me.ListBox1.Items 
            SW.WriteLine(itm) 
        Next 
    End Using 
End If
```

Comment: Can't you just loop through the items in the list box and append them to a text file?  Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: i know how to save them to a textfile using savedialog but that saving them to whatever directory program user wants i want it to save autmatically to program directory so then i can use the text file to populate other listbox

Comment: @user3459587 When you refer to `program directory` are you talking about the Application Domain or Program Files or Program Data?

Comment: I think program files or program data, wherever the program stores it data it needs to run, here is the code i have 

`   SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"

        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then

            Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, False)

                For Each itm As String In Me.ListBox1.Items
                    SW.WriteLine(itm)
                Next
            End Using
        End If`

Comment: @user3459587 Remove the code from the comment an update the question with your code please.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. If you ask users to upload the file, then you should save it to your db and use the copy from db to populate the other listbox.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of research on your part would've helped you understand what you are trying to accomplish better.

1. How do I get Program Data directory? `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData`
2. How do I Write multiple lines to file?  `File.WriteAllLines()`
3. How do I Read multiple lines from a file? `File.ReadAllLines()`

Once you understand the basics you can easily put them together

Create two List boxes, and one button on your WinForm:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.

    'Get the Program Data Directory (This is hidden by default by the OS.)
    Dim strPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData
    Dim fileName As String = "myFile.txt"
    Dim fullPath = Path.Combine(strPath, fileName)

    Dim data As String() = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"}

    'Save the items to ListBox1 First
    For Each item As String In data
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next

    'Now write the items to the textfile, line by line.
    File.WriteAllLines(fullPath, data)

    'Read all lines we just saved and load them onto an array of strings.
    Dim tempAllLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fullPath)

    'Display each  on ListBox2 by iterating the array.
    For Each line As String In tempAllLines
        ListBox2.Items.Add(line)
    Next
End Sub
```

Here, I created this form so you can get an idea of what i'm referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to the current executable's folder like this:

```
folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

However, that will only work if the executable is a .NET assembly.  Otherwise, you could use the first argument in the command line (which is the full executable file path), like this:

```
folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0))
```

If, on the other hand, you want to get the path of the current assembly (which may be different than the executable that loaded it) you could do this:

```
folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Or, if you want to just get the current directory, you could use this:

```
folderPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Once you have the folder path, you can add the file name to it with `Path.Combine`, like this:

```
filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)
```

However, it's not recommended that you write data directly to the program's running path, since the user may not have permission to write to that folder.  Using the program data folder would certainly be better, but even that can be risky:

```
folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyAppName")
```

The recommended place to store data from .NET apps is [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).